# How to insert 1 Blank Row every X Rows in Google Sheets (App Script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like the script to start at Row 3 and then insert a new Row every 17th Row until the end of the Sheet. But I am not really sure how to go about this, especially since adding a new Row results in the number of rows being changed, every time a new Row is inserted.

I have found a similar answer using VBA for Excel, but nothing specific for Google App Script and Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 18 instead of 17 for every loop. You may try something like this:

```
function addRow17() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var row = 3

  while (row < sh.getLastRow()){
    sh.insertRowAfter(row)
    row = row+18
    Logger.log(row)
  }
}
```